# Can I clear, or permanently delete, deleted question & answers?

Tags: support, deleted-posts-pages

Can I clear my questions & answers which are deleted?

For example, on Ask Ubuntu, I can see a list of my [recently deleted answers](https://askubuntu.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/256099) in my profile.

I want to clear this list, I don't require an "Undelete" button. (Say permanently delete.)

Can I permanently delete these questions & answers, so that they're visible neither by me nor by moderators?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can I clear Deleted Questions & Answers by me?

No, you can't.

Once they are older than 90 days they will no longer appear in that list.

---

As a side note - we don't "permanently delete" things. Deleted items are not rendered for users except for the author, moderators and high reputation users (typically +10k).

Comment: You said older than 90 days no longer appear in list then also these Q/A is no longer to access for who has 10k or more reputations (moderator) after 90 days?

Comment: No, moderators and +10k users will be able to see these (if they go to the page they are on), as will you. I am specifically talking about the "deleted recent questions/answers" lists in your profile page.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot permanently delete questions and answers. Deleted questions and answers are visible to users with 10,000 reputation or more. So, you cannot permanently delete them and there is no button to clear this history. There is also not really a reason to clear it, because it is only visible to you and to moderators.